# BerryGSM connection through serial port

Tags: rf, raspberry-pi, serial

I’m looking to use the GSM module BerryGSM

https://thepihut.com/products/ozzmaker-berrygps-gsm

It says on the website that you can use the serial port instead instead of the USB interface.

I’m looking to use this device without the USB connector.

The issue I’m having is that I can’t find information on how to connect the device through the serial port, their are 2 header pins called PI_TX and PI_RX but not sure if they are for the serial communication?

I also have a copy of the schematic
http://ozzmaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/BerryGPS-GSM-Schematic-V1.4.pdf

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for the part? It should describe the pin functions, necessary voltages, etc.

Comment: No all it’s has it’s an overview page https://ozzmaker.com/berrygps-gsm-overview/

Comment: Without the device or a datasheet in front of me, I don't feel confident enough to give a solid answer. The guide seems to suggest that the correct serial pins may be connected when the device is connected to a Pi using its standard mounting, but I can't really tell.

Comment: I have a copy of the schematic if that would help?

Comment: It should; please [edit] it into your post. I likely won't have a chance to review today, however.

Comment: I’ve added it in

Comment: The resolution on that schematic is unusably low. If you zoom it you can see that it's a blur and text is not readable: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBha1.png

Comment: I’ve included the link now

Comment: Based on the datasheet I'd assume PI_TX and PI_RX are correct - they seem to go through the serial port mux and level shifter and reach the serial ports on the devices. JP1 and JP3 will need to be set accordingly to route the signal properly.

Comment: Okay thank you so I will need to set both JP1 and JP3 to true (solder then both together)

Comment: No, JP3 both set high connects the serial port to the unused line Y3, according to the schematic notes to the right of U6. JP3 looks like it should always be low, while JP1 should be set depending on which device you want to actually reach. Low for GPS, high for SARA via the level shifter.